# Pokemon GO: I want to play, but have no data

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm a teenager, so my parents are paying for my cellular plan, and have restricted my phone to be unable to use any cellular data. This means I cannot use it what so ever, I really want to play games like Pokemon GO which require the player to use cellular data? Any help?

by the way, im on an iPhone 6s+, running 9.3.3 and im jailbroken.

Comment: You need a data connection or you’re sunk. Maybe wifi?

Comment: Find a friend who also plays, and has an unlimited data plan, then tether his phone. I personally know a couple of friends who do this. The caveat is that they always have to play at the same time, so be good to your friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can play the game on a wifi connection without data, but since most wifi connections are location locked, you will not be able to take advantage of most of the game, such as hatching eggs or hunting around for pokemon. You will only be able to log in and catch whatever pokemon spawn at your location. I've heard of people trying to play by moving between wifi locations to simulate movement to the GPS and app, but so far I have not heard of that working.

Comment: Could have a friend with a data plan broadcast wifi from their phone and follow you around, if you’re desperate.